# While != "specific string" loop mishap

Tags: python, loops, file, while-loop, exit

I'm trying to make a task a little more efficient. I'm going to continue to research/edit while moving forward.

What the code currently does is ask for your first/last name it then outputs a username & password. Up to this point it works fine if there is a more efficient way to rewrite this  also appreciated.

The only thing I still need to fix is looping entries(First_name and Last_name) so I can have multiple users added with a \n\n for easy reading/separation of each user. preferably with a exit command such such as "done"

I'm also going to be looking into how to create a new file that this information is stored in but this is the section I'm going to try to figure out.

```py
First_name = input("Enter your First name: ")
Last_name= input("Enter your last name: ")


Username = str(First_name) + str(Last_name)
Password = Username + str('1!')


print("Username: ", Username.upper())
print("Password: ", Password)
```

In terms of trying to solve the issue.

I did try to create something in the ball park of..

```py
First_name = input("Enter your First name: ")
Last_name= input("Enter your last name: ")

while First_name != "done":
    Last_name= input("Enter your last name: ")
    First_name = input("Enter your First name: ")
    Last_name= input("Enter your last name: ")
    Username = str(First_name) + str(Last_name)
    Password = Username + str('1!')
    print("Username: ", Username.upper())
    print("Password: ", Password)
```

this just repeated the first two lines without printing the Username/password. It also appeared to acknowledge when I typed done but slightly off from desired. Below I included how the code ran

```
Enter your First name: first
Enter your last name: last
Enter your last name: last
Enter your First name: done
Enter your last name: last
Username:  DONELAST
Password:  donelast1!
```

I get why its first, last, last, first last. I dont get how to make the while loop using "while Fist_name !='done': "  without putting lines 1 and 2 before the loop. I tried removing the inputs at line 5 and 6 but then it just looped the username and password.

Comment: remove the first two lines and the first line inside the while loop. You ask for 5 inputs before printing. Just have `First_name = ''` before the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop and break it when the first name is `done`.

```
while True:
    first_name = input("Enter your first name (done to exit): ")
    if first_name.lower() == "done":
        print("Done!")
        break
    last_name = input("Enter your last name: ")
    Username = str(first_name) + str(last_name)
    Password = Username + str('1!')
    print("Username: ", Username.upper())
    print("Password: ", Password)
    print("\n")
```

Output:

```
Enter your first name (done to exit): John
Enter your last name: Doe
Username:  JOHNDOE
Password:  JohnDoe1!


Enter your first name (done to exit): Alice
Enter your last name: Court
Username:  ALICECOURT
Password:  AliceCourt1!


Enter your first name (done to exit): done
Done!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your variables to an empty string before the loop starts. Since an empty string is not equal to `done` your code will enter the loop and prompt the user:

```
First_Name = ''
Last_Name = ''
while First_name != "done":
    Last_name= input("Enter your last name: ")
    First_name = input("Enter your First name: ")    
    Username = str(First_name) + str(Last_name)
    Password = Username + str('1!')
    print("Username: ", Username.upper())
    print("Password: ", Password)
```